# "Got it at" or "Got it in?"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

If someone asked you where you bought something, you could say,

> I got it **at** Walmart.

but what if instead of referring to a store you were referring to a city?

Would you say,

> I got it **at** Chicago.

or

> I got it **in** Chicago.

Somehow when referring to a city, using "in" instead of "at" seems more appropriate. Am I right? Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Walmart* and *Chicago* are both places, but we use different prepositions to refer to them. From this [article on them](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/prepositions.htm):

> **Prepositions of Place: at, on, and in**
>
> We use **at** for specific addresses.
>   *Grammar English lives at 55 Boretz Road in Durham.*
>
> We use **on** to designate names of streets, avenues, etc.
>   *Her house is on Boretz Road.*
>
> And we use **in** for the names of land-areas (towns, counties, states, countries, and continents).
>
> *She lives in Durham.*
>
> *Durham is in Windham County.*
>
> *Windham County is in Connecticut.*

Because *Walmart* is a specific place or address, we say that someone shops *at Walmart*. However, since *Chicago* is a land-area, we say that someone shops *in Chicago*.

Comment: love this answer Clears up alot for me. +1

Comment: IMHO, many Walmarts these days are so big that you could say "in". Still, it would sound a little weird, unless you are trying to imply that "it" is something unrelated to Walmart itself (eg: a disease).