# "at" or "in" with the city 's name

Tags: prepositions

This question is about the use of preposition 'at'.

In this passage:

> In 715 CE, ten years after the foundation of the Umayyad Mosque at Damascus, the Umayyad Caliph Al-Walid engaged in the construction of the mosque that was to equal the former.

Why did they use "at"? I think it should be replaced by "in", I am confused.

This passge is taken from muslimheritage.com, and I'm studying the translation of it into Arabic in my university.

Comment: The general question is well covered at ['got it at' or 'got it in?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36843/got-it-at-or-got-it-in), but not this tweak.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["At" vs. "in" followed by a city name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124755/at-vs-in-followed-by-a-city-name) @Shoe's answer: 'The choice of _in_ or _at_ with a city depends on how speakers conceive that city in the context of the statement they are making.

If the city is [being] conceived as a two-dimensional place in which to live and work, then _in_ is the usual preposition. If, on the other hand, the city is conceived as a single point rather than as a place with dimensions, then [at] is the common choice. ...'. 'We'll stop to eat at Rhyl.'

Comment: It's always stuck in my memory that, when I was learning the piano as a child, I had a music book that said "W.A. Mozart - born **at** Salzburg 1756, died **in** Vienna 1791". - presumably because Vienna is a much bigger city - and similar with other composers' birthplaces.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. In conclusion, both of "at" and "in" can be followed by name of city. Only the  context indicates to the most suitable one. isn't right? @Edwin Ashworth

Comment: Yes; I'd say that 'in Paris' etc is far more common than 'at Paris': you have to think a lot harder to come up with examples where the latter is the natural choice. 'Our Eurostar terminates at Paris and we transfer to Honfleur.' [[RailtrailTours](https://www.railtrail.co.uk/)]

Answer (score 3):

**at** is grammatical, as is **in**.  The **at `<place-name>`** collocation is frequently used in contexts where `<place-name>` is a landmark or a (notable) destination, whereas **in** refers to the place as a *locale* or *environs*, as a place that has a boundary.

Consider [this text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_books):

> Clay tablets were used *in Mesopotamia* in the 3rd millennium BCE. The calamus, an instrument with a triangular point, was used to inscribe characters in moist clay. Fire was used to dry the tablets out. *At Nineveh*, over 20,000 tablets have been found, dating from the 7th century BCE; *this was the archive and library of the kings of Assyria*, who had workshops of copyists and conservationists at their disposal

[*my emphasis*]

Comment: Can you add a supporting reference?

Comment: Just years of reading, especially history.  But I'll see if I can find an authority that discusses this use of **at**.

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stop+at+Honolulu+en+route%2Cstop+in+Honolulu+en+route&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) the NGram chart to show the usage. Apparently we're much more likely to stop ***at*** Honolulu en route to somewhere else than to stop ***in*** Honolulu. I think "en route" is relevant there, though (because it makes Honolulu *a "landmark" staging point within a longer journey*).

Comment: I think *at* in constructions like this is now archaic, but if you read lots of books written in previous centuries, you would have seen it used quite a bit.

Comment: @PeterShor: Are you saying that **at** as in "At Nineveh" is an archaism?

Comment: @Tim: That's exactly what I'm saying. [See this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=church+at+London%2Cchurch+in+London&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) "church at London" was reasonably common in the 18th and 19th centuries, but today it occurs at 1/40 the frequency of "church in London".

Comment: @PeterShor So much weight is not to be placed on ngram. Compare *The American Consulate at Ponta Delgada assumes no responsibility for the professional competence or integrity of the persons or firms listed.*

Comment: "A set of power at rest in front of the old Rock Island RR station at Iowa City" (1987)  https://www.flickr.com/photos/john_leopard/50670247277/

Comment: @Tim: It may not be an archaism quite yet, but it's well on its way to becoming one. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=American+Consulate+in%2C+American+Consulate+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that in 1930, "American Consulate at" was six times more common than "American Consulate in". Now, it's the other way around.

Comment: @PeterShor: It's not moribund. It's just a particular usage where the context that warrants "at" is not as common as the situation that warrants "in".

Comment: "The Idea of Order At Key West" by Wallace Stevens. tryfoundation.org/poems/43431/the-idea-of-order-at-key-west

Comment: Wallace Stevens wrote that poem in 1934, nearly 90 years ago. You can't use it to support the idea that *in* isn't replacing *at* in these constructions in the 21st century.

Comment: @PeterShor: The train was 1987 and the consulate was 2011.  The Stevens example shows the usage.